# Is there a term that describes hating "sunset" moment?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are terms that are used to describe something we like or dislike.  For example, the term "*[nyctophilia](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nyctophobia)*" means  loving or preferring the darkness.
Is there is a term that describes disliking sunset?

Comment: the link is directed at *nyctophobia*

Comment: If there is an actual phobia, you may use a hyphen: *sunset-phobic*.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't a single word for "disliking sunset" (or at least, I know of no such term). There also isn't any obvious way to form one.

Just as the Ancient Greek word for "night" is *nyx,* with the combining form *nyct(o)-,* the Ancient Greek word for "sunset" seems to be *[heliodysion](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dh(liodu%2Fsion),* which I think would have the combining form *heliodysi(o)-.* (Note: there are other Greek and Latin roots meaning things like "twilight" and "dusk".)

However, there's no good way I know of to take it from there and find or invent a noun meaning "dislike of sunset".

Usually, nouns ending in *-phobia* refer to fears. In some cases, they refer to more generalized aversions (such as *hydrophobia*) but this is not the semantic center of the suffix. So **heliodysiophobia* seems off.

One affix used in words derived from Greek that does indicate "disike" is *mis(o)-,* as in *misogyny* or *misanthropy.* However, it's not particularly productive, especially not for nouns, and **misheliodysy* or **miseliodysy* look weird and are incomprehensible (I'm also not all that confident that these would be the correct forms).

Comment: Maybe as a coinage, "crepuscophobia", which would mean fear of twilight, at both sunrise & sunset.

Comment: The Greeks had a couple of deities (namely, Hespera and Astraeus) assigned to the dusk.  Conceivably you could suffix "-phobic" to one of their names and coin something not-too-outlandish that way.  Indeed, around the web I see that "hesperophobic" is used as "fear of the west", or more precisely "fear of Western culture".

Comment: @jamesqf: I don't know if "crepuscul-" is such a great root to use in this case. For one thing, it's Latin, not Greek. Also, I get the sense that it refers mainly to the dusk or darkness that comes after sunset.

Comment: @DougWarren: Good point about "hesper-" also being able to indicate sunset/evening. Based on what you say, it doesn't seem like a word meaning "hatred of sunset" could be formed from this root, since "hesperophobia" is already used with another meaning.